# Meaning of 作った人たち

Tags: meaning

I ran recently across the following sentence here: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012067221000/k10012067221000.html

映画を見た大学生は「すてきな絵や細かい表現で、**作った人たち**の気持ちを感じました」と話していました。

The text is about an anime-movie.
Does  作った人たち mean in this context "the people who where drawn(made)", i.e. the characters? Meaning that the students could sense or feel the feelings of the characters in the movie?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, I think that

> 作った人たち

means

> the people who made [the movie]

I will guess a translation for your sentence:

> 映画を見た大学生は「すてきな絵や細かい表現で、作った人たちの気持ちを感じました」と話していました。The university students that watched the movie were saying that "they experienced the feeling of the people who made [the movie] through the lovely pictures and the detailed expressions".

The caveat here is that, in verb sentences that come just right in front of the noun they modify, the noun can be either the object or the subject, and you need to rely on the context to figure it out.

For example, consider these sentences with the verb 買う

> ① 買った本。The book [someone] bought.
>
> ② すしを買った人。The person who bought sushi.

At ①, the noun (本) modified by 買った is the object. At ②, on the contrary, the noun (人) modified by 買った is the subject.

Comment: `through the lovely pictures` -- Hm, are you aware that the で in すてきな絵や細かい表現**で** is the continuative form of the copula だ, not the particle で ?

Comment: I don't see why it makes a difference here

Answer (score 5):

No, 作った人たち is "people who created (the movie)", i.e., the staff. This is simply because 作る means "to make/create" and there is no passive voice involved. The guy is saying "I could feel the passion of the creators."